# If $A$ and $B$ are integral domains, how to make $A\times B$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

I've been lately reading a bit of ring theory and when I reached the 'Integral Domains' section a question suddenly arised and it seems pretty natural to me. It is clear that if $A$ and $B$ are integral domains, then $A\times B$ is not neccesarily an integral domain (if the product on $A\times B$ is defined by $(a,b)(a',b')=(aa',bb')$). In fact, if $A$, and $B$ are rings with unit, $A\times B$ is NOT an integral domain as $(1,0')(0,1')=(0,0')$. The question is

> Is it possible to define a 'canonical' product on $A\times B$ in order to make it into an integral domain?

With 'canonical' I mean 'definable from the operations on $A$ and $B$, or from some fixed relation between them' (for example, when the semi-direct product on groups is defined it only depends on a certain homomorphism from a group $G$ to the automorphism group of another group $H$).

I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an explicit example: When you consider complex numbers $a+i\cdot b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ would $(a,b) := a+i\cdot b$ do?

Comment: @Moritz sure, as $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain. However, it is not a product on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JosePaternina Yes, it is. It's the product defined by $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$.

Comment: @Arthur Oh, ok, that makes sense. Awesome.

Comment: @RobArthan I was thinking in gaussian integers and making a mess in my head. My bad.

Comment: It doesn't work for any domain, though. Just look at $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, where the same product definition makes $(1,1)\cdot(1,1)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the process that creates $\Bbb{C}$ from $\Bbb{R}$, called [Dickson doubling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Dickson_construction), doesn't give what Jose wants in general.You either lose commutativity or gain non-trivial zero divisors.

Comment: Does the category of integral domains have products?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling: no, but that isn't the question here.

Answer (score 16):

This is not possible in general. Two well-known facts are that a finite integral domain is a field, and that a finite field must have a prime power number of elements. Thus, for instance, there is no way to give $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ the structure of an integral domain.

Comment: +1. Very thorough answer! For the OP, let me give a proof of a weakening of the cited result: that any **commutative** integral domain is a field. Consider the map $f: x\mapsto ax$ for nonzero $a\in D$. I claim this map is injective. Why? Well, otherwise we would have $ax=ay$ for some $x\not=y$, which in turn would yield $a(x-y)=0$ - a contradiction to the fact that $D$ is an integral domain. But since $D$ is finite, $f$ being injective means $f$ is surjective! So in particular $1\in im(f)$, and so $a$ has a multiplicative inverse in $D$. (cont'd)

Comment: What about the non-commutative case? Well, it turns out that the result is still true - every finite integral domain, (a priori) commutative or not, is a field. However, the proof is significantly harder: see [Wedderburn's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy#The_arithmetical_hierarchy_of_formulas).

Comment: EDIT: I messed up: integral domains are, by definition, commutative, so the only argument needed is that of my first comment. A possibly non-commutative integral domain is just called a **domain**.

Comment: Finite non-commutative domains are still going to be skew fields (by the same argument that shows that finite integral domains are fields), and thus fields (by Wedderburn's little theorem).

Comment: Great, that's a nice argument. So, we must just ignore the finite case, as such a process could exist only in the case that both domains have prime power order.

Comment: Even in that case, I'm not sure how to canonically construct the field structure. The first idea would be a structure transportation, but it depends on a function from the direct product into the field.

Answer (score 2):

If $B=A$ and there exists a polynomial $x^2+ax+b\in A[x]$ which has no zeros in the field of fractions of $A$, then we can define a multiplication on $A\times A$ by mimicking the multiplication on the integral domain $A[x]/\left(x^2+ax+b\right)$.  That is, we can define a multiplication on $A\times A$ as
$$(p,q)\cdot (r,s):=(pr-bqs,ps+qr-aqs)\,,$$
for all $p,q,r,s\in A$.  This is very much how we get $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{F}_4$ as $\mathbb{F}_2\times\mathbb{F}_2$, $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right]$ as $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, etc.

Comment: 1) Your proposal certainly does work for any integral domain $A$. 2) it doesn't answer the question, even under the assumption that $A = B$, because you don't have a canonical choice for the coefficients in the polynomial $x^2+ax+b$.

Comment: I know that my answer is not canonical.  It doesn't make sense to ask for a canonical one either, since there is no canonical way to double an integral domain.  It doesn't hurt to propose ways to doubling some integral domains, does it?  Thanks for the remark 1) by the way.

Comment: A proof that there is no canonical way to double an integral domain would be a good answer to this question. You've just made this claim. Can you prove it?

Comment: If there were a canonical way, then there would be an integral domain that doubles $\mathbb{C}$, but this would imply the existence of an irreducible quadratic polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.